# Power BI - Expression.Error: We cannot convert the value null to type List

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I am getting this error when running my power query. Sometimes it refreshes successfully and sometimes it gives me this error. How do I fix this? Is it a data type I have to change?

```
Expression.Error:
We cannot convert the value null to type List.
Details:
    Value=
    Type=[Type]
```

Here is the query that threw an error sometimes it refreshes:

```
let

List = List.Generate(
    () => [i=0, x = ""],
    each [i] <= Count,
    each [
        i = [i] + 1,
        x =
        Table.FromRows(((Table.SelectRows(API, each [Index] = i)[Value]){0})[DataResult], { 

            "Date",                
            "Region",
            "Location",
            "Name",
            "VPN",
            "Category",
            "Network",   
            "Percentage",
            "BadQualityCount",
            "UnknownCount",
            "CallCount"
            
        })
    ]
),

Result = Table.FromRecords(List),
Result2 = Table.Skip(Result,1),
DataResultTable = Table.Combine(Result2[x]),
DataResultTableWithTypes = Table.TransformColumnTypes(DataResultTable,{            
  
            {"Date", Date.Type}, 
            {"Region", type text},
            {"Location", type text},
            {"Name", type text},
            {"VPN", type text},
            {"Category", type text},
            {"Network", type text},
            {"Percentage", type number},
            {"BadQualityCount", Int64.Type},
            {"UnknownCount", Int64.Type},
            {"CallCount", Int64.Type}

            }),

Output = Table.SelectRows(DataResultTableWithTypes, each true)

in
    Output
```

Comment: please post your code

Comment: @horseyride I have posted the code

Comment: and which step crashes?

Comment: @horseyride the step that crashed was the List.Generate

Comment: I guess issue is in the step > List = List.Generate... If there are possibilities of 0 rows return from the inner part of that step, you need to handle that properly.

Comment: @mkRabbani I don't think it is the zero rows returning. I think it's the value = NULL, which that causes the error. I don't know if there is a way to have it listed as 0 instead of NULL. Is that possible?